# Observe requisition list add to cart event

Tags: addtocart, b2b

I have an event observer listening on `checkout_cart_product_add_after` which works when adding products to the cart from the product, category, and wishlist pages, but when adding products to the cart from the B2B requisition list that event is not fired.

I haven't been able to find anything as to why that event does not fire when adding products from a requisition list. I'm hoping someone here knows of a similar event that is fired when adding products to the cart from a requisition list because I have not been able to find anything on this short of reading the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having create a plugin for `afterPlaceItemsInCart` in `\Magento\RequisitionList\Model\RequisitionListManagement`. Below is the basics of what I used.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\RequisitionList;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

/**
 * Class is responsible for actions with requisition list items.
 */
class RequisitionListManagement {
    
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;


    public function __construct(
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function afterPlaceItemsInCart(\Magento\RequisitionList\Model\RequisitionListManagement $subject, $result) {
        $cartItems = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

        // Did all my stuff here

        $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();

        return $result;
    }
}
```